# What are good programs for writing expressions?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

By writing expressions, I mean intermediate expressions to "show your work," such as the ones in the below image. LaTex would seem like overkill for such problems.

[image: Expressions]

Comment: LaTeX. If you don't want to use your normal word processor, use LaTeX.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ is a big **beauty**

Comment: LaTeX is both a markup language and a program (which converts that markup language into something like PDF). I get the argument that LaTeX the program seems like overkill for this task (though I don't generally agree with it), but LaTeX the markup language is perfectly suited. I presume this question is asking about the program, rather than the markup language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I still think LaTeX is the way to go.  Once you start having to write several mathematical expressions, any kind of mouse-driven system for specifying them is going to become very frustrating.  LaTeX is extremely efficient for doing exactly what you want to do.

```
\begin{align*}
        c_1x + a     &= c_2 x + b \\
        c_1x + a - a &= c_2x + b - a\\ 
        c_1x         &= c_2x + b - a \\
        c_1x - c_2 x &= c_2x + b - a - c_2 x \\
        c_1x - c_2 x &= b - a \\
        x            &= \frac{b-a}{c_1 - c_2}
    \end{align*}
```

\begin{align*}
    c_1x + a     &= c_2 x + b \\
    c_1x + a - a &= c_2x + b - a\\ 
    c_1x         &= c_2x + b - a \\
    c_1x - c_2 x &= c_2x + b - a - c_2 x \\
    c_1x - c_2 x &= b - a \\
    x            &= \frac{b-a}{c_1-c_2}
\end{align*}

See [Getting started with LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/begin.html) for some pointers.